# Simple bar code generator

Tags: barcode

I am looking for a barcode generator, free and compatible with Windows XP or greater.

Comment: What type of barcodes do you want to generate?

Comment: @ephilip I am interested in common linear barcodes

Comment: Do you want a desktop application, or is an online one OK?

Comment: @ephilip I would prefer desktop applications, but if there aren't free I have no problem use online apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as online barcode generators go, [this one](http://www.terryburton.co.uk/barcodewriter/generator/) looks like one that would suit your needs.  You could also use Wolfram|Alpha, if you wanted to.  Or, as an alternative, you could download a barcode font and use that, as a previous poster mentioned.  [Here's](http://www.barcodegen.com/) a desktop one that looks handy.  (And that's compatible with Windows XP)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do. But for simple barcodes, you can install a font and use it to "generate" barcodes. Search for "barcode font".

Answer (score 1):

My favorite barcode generator is [Zint Barcode Generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/), it can generate a lot of codes including Code 128, Data Matrix, USPS OneCode, EAN-128, UPC/EAN, ITF, QR Code, Code 16k, PDF417, MicroPDF417, LOGMARS, Maxicode, GS1 DataBar, Aztec, Composite Symbols and more.  You can save the barcodes in PNG, EPS and SVG, and it is free.